# Print Oracle Pl/sql Cursor

Tags: plsql, oracle-cursor

Can I directly open and print cursor in begin end block without using loops?
or without reading each column and printing it individually for each row.

Comment: This depends on the SQL client you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display one record there is no need for looping in your cursor.
If multiple then you need looping in cursor.
Eg In  `**Test_Project**` Table has two column:-

```
projectid           projectname 

p2                  Programming     
p1                 Search Engine    
p3                 Testing
```

--Below is the code to display one record without using loop

```
Declare 

   cprojname varchar2(2000)   ;

   CURSOR c1
   IS
      select project_name from test_project WHERE projectid='p1';

BEGIN

   OPEN c1;
   FETCH c1 INTO cprojname;

   if c1%notfound then
      cprojname := 'no data';
   else
   dbms_output.put_line(cprojname);

   end if;

   CLOSE c1;

END;
```

o/p:- Search Engine